# Spring AMQP Multiple Vhosts

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I currently need to utilize three vhosts for this application. I am only receiving messages over one as a consumer, and the others for RPC calls. Currently I am using `CachingConnectionFactory` that I have subclassed one for each virtual host. Then I am making each of those subclasses beans. I can then of course grab the connection factory to create the `RabbitTemplate` for the correct vhost instance.

I saw in the documentation about the `AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory` but wanted to know if there are any reasons I should refactor my currently working code. I want the most maintainable and perfomant solution, not the "easiest" one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why you felt it was necessary to subclass the `CachingConnectionFactory` you can simply declare multiple factories...

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="default" host="localhost" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="foo" host="localhost" virtual-host="/foo" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="bar" host="localhost" virtual-host="/bar" />
```

Whether or not you using a routing connection factory (e.g. `SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory`) depends on your application needs. If you don't use it you would need 3 `RabbitTemplate`s and decide which one to use at runtime.

With a routing connection factory, the `RabbitTemplate` can make the decision based on the message content with a `send-connection-factory-selector-expression`.

There's not really a lot of difference except the second decouples your application from the decision. For example, you can set a message header `customerId` before sending (or during message conversion if you're using a `convertAndSend` method) and use a selector expression such as `@vhostFor.select(messageProperties.headers.customerId)`.

If you later add a new vhost you wouldn't have to change your main application, just your `vhostFor` lookup bean to pick the right vhost.

Comment: I'm sorry I did subclass the connectionfactory, I just used three different ones and wire them up with qualifiers.